# How to handle no request on servlet

Tags: java, jsp, jquery-mobile, servlets, jetty

I have a .jsp page where I've coded a form that submits some input to a servlet. The servlet manipulates the input and then sends a message to the same page. This is working fine, however, when I get back to the .jsp page, or in other words, when I get the answer from the servlet, the url that is visible in the browser contains the path to the servlet (e.g http:/index.jsp/servlet_name ), so, when I refresh the page, the browser redirects to the servlet and it get stuck because there was no get/post submission, so doGet() or doPost() are never active.. Is it possible to handle no get/post request in the servlet ? If not, how should I handle this problem ?

Ps: I'm using jquery mobile to build the pages (in the event of a possible solution with this framework)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you got it wrong. Even when you refresh, normally either doGet() / doPost() is activated. Your browser often asks you first if you're refreshing post requests.

What could be happening is your servlet is serving another request without form data, hence you get the impression it's not doing anything

Comment: Yes, you're right, doGet() is activated by default, I didn't know this.. I've solved the problem, thanks :) . @gerrytan